# How to search and copy output of Ex commands run in command-line mode in Vim?

Tags: vim

Some command-line mode commands (i.e. the Ex commands, not shell commands) in Vim can produce output that are several line longs. I have two questions about it.

- How can I search for a particular word in it?
- How can I copy something from it and paste it into the buffer I am editing?

I see that in my Vim, the `more` pager is used when the output is more than one screen full, so I think that brings more complexity to this question because the solution may differ when the `more` pager is involved.

Comment: FWIW, this is not the `more` pager but a much more limited internal one.

Answer (score 3):

EDITED because I originally misunderstood the question:

`help :redir` should tell you how to do it. For a specific example:

```
:redir @h
:silent highlight
:redir END
"hp
```

Start redirection to the register `h`, run your command without showing it on the screen (and without running it through the pager), stop the redirection, paste the contents of the `h` register.

Comment: `:r! cmd` seems to be accepting a shell command, not a command-line mode command. e.g. With this I can execute something like `:r !ps` but not something like `:r !highlight`.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the question.